# matlab - get date in month/year format from datenum number format

Tags: matlab

I have a table which contains the year and the month in a "double" format.

I then create a datenum for each entry in the table:

```
for j=1:number_of_rows
dates_returns_all_period_monthly(j,10)=datenum([year,month,1]);
end
```

First of all, is there a way to have the dates on a monthly basis without having to set the day on the datenum command?

Secondly, the previous commands give me values such as `731947` for

I then want to get the date in a date format,

I am trying to run the following command:

```
dates_returns_all_period_monthly(j,11)=datestr(dates_returns_all_period_monthly(j,10));
```

but I get an error `"Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts"`

How can I fix this? Ideally I would like to have something like January 2004, February 2005, etc.. or 01/2004, 02/2004, something like that, because later on I want to plot with the dates on the x-axis, and I don't want to have `731947` etc. as values.

Comment: I think you are looking for `datetime` instead of `datenum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to put a string output into a matrix array. This won't work: it will try and convert the string to an array of numbers, and your indexing will tell it to try to put your array of numbers into a single matrix location, causing the error that you are seeing.

What you'll need to do if you wish to store them is to create a cell array, which store arbitrary data inside each element location, but require different syntax to access:

```
text_dates = cell(1,number_of_rows);
for j=1:number_of_rows
    text_dates{j}=datestr(dates_returns_all_period_monthly(j,10));
end
```

You won't be able to use these directly as part of the `plot` command however - Matlab needs inputs to plot to be numeric, so strings will not work. What you want to do is create your plot using your numeric values, then access the current axis properties (you can use the `gca` command to get this) and change the `XTickLabel' properties to the strings you wish, e.g.:

```
plot(dates_returns_all_period_monthly(:,10),whatever_your_y_values_are);
ax=gca;
set(gca,'XTickLabels',text_dates);
```

Comment: Sorry, it seems like not all values are plotted on the x-axis. It seems like since only 6 values are printed for the initial x-axis values, the first 6 values are arbitrarily chosen from the text ones as well. Is there a way to print the correct values? `plot(yearlab,sigmean(:,1))
datetick('x','keepticks','keeplimits')
ax=gca;
set(gca,'XTickLabels',yearlab_monthly);
title('plot title')`

Comment: Yep, you need to also set your "XTick" manually. Modify your `set(gca,'XTickLabels',yearlab_monthly);` to be `set(gca,'XTick',yearlab,'XTickLabels',yearlab_monthly);

Comment: If I use `set(gca,'XTick',yearlab,'XTickLabels',yearlab_monthly);` it puts so many values on the x-axis that I can see nothing. How can I fix that?

Comment: Well you have to decide how many Ticks you think is appropriate for your graph, and modify the expression as desired, e.g.: `set(gca,'XTick',yearlab(1:10:end),'XTickLabels',yearlab_monthly(1:10:end));` or `set(gca,'XTick',yearlab(1:100:end),'XTickLabels',yearlab_monthly(1:100:end));`

Comment: Thanks Hugh. Do you know how I can plot the xtick and the xticklabel only selected dates? Let's suppose I want to have an xtick and an xticklabel only for January 2004, December 2005, November 2010, and so on.. If I use `set(gca,'xtick',[yearlab(1);yearlab(10);yearlab(15)],'xticklabel',[yearlab_monthly(1);yearlab_monthly(10);yearlab_monthly(15)]);` it plots these consecutively in the three first ticks, but I would like them to be plotted in the correct positions. Thanks.

Comment: That looks like it should be doing what you are asking - in what way is it wrong? Where are the ticks, and where are they supposed to be? Simple example which works for me: `figure;plot(1:100);set(gca,'xtick',[1 10 50],'xticklabel',{'one','ten','fifty'});`